# Dynamically generated href won't show properly

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make this link appear on my page, but it won't return the /register path, it'll just go immediately the UTMs.... On the site it'll show the href as

```
domain.com/?utm_campaign...
```

instead of

```
domain.com/register?utm_campaign...
```

Why is that and how can that be fixed?

```
<script>
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
// get the required parameter
const campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign');
const source = urlParams.get('utm_source');
const medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium');

var registerationURL = new URL('../register?utm_campaign=&utm_source=&utm_medium=');
registerationURL.searchParams.set('utm_campaign', campaign);
registerationURL.searchParams.set('utm_source', source);
registerationURL.searchParams.set('utm_medium', medium);

var a = document.getElementbyID('test').innerHTML;
a.href = registerationURL;

</script>

<a id="test" href="#">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementbyID('test').innerHTML` returns the string "Click here". Remove the `.innerHTML` and it should work.

However, this can be done much simpler with the following

```
var registrationUrl = location.origin + '/register' + location.search;
```